# Initiate workflow when item added to network folder?

Tags: sharepoint, csv, workflow

I am new to Sharepoint, but because I have development experience I am the 'Sharepoint Guy'. Sorry to all the professionals that I am giving a bad name, I am working on it - I swear!

We have a process that requires owners of Groups in Active Directory to approve all the members of the respective groups, twice a year. So far, our solution is a powershell script that reaches out to a text file listing the groups, and spits out a CSV with each group, group members and the owner of that group.

We'd like to be able to stick the .CSV in a network folder (shared library? not sure if that's right), have a workflow started that reads the contents, and sends emails to the owners of the groups so that they can approve (verify) their ownership, and that all members belong in the group.

Is this possible, or am I going about it the wrong way? I am awaiting formal Sharepoint training, so I have to teach myself in the interim.

We are using Sharepoint 2010 + Nintex Workflow 2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/

I will initiate a workflow when an item gets dropped into that library, using mapped drives! I will configure my script to drop it in the mapped drive, problem solved. Hope this helps someone in the future!